# Capybara and page.body

Tags: capybara

I've got Capybara installed on Rails but, if I drop into the debugger in my steps.rb file, and check out the contents of page.body it's always empty.

Completely clueless how to proceed.
Should I check if Capybara is loaded in the environment - if so, how?

Should I initialize Capybara somewhere - if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you visit your page?  Sorry, I know it sounds silly but it's all I can think of given the above information.  Can you try page.find('body') work instead?

Like this:

```
describe 'home page' do
  before :each do
    visit root_path
  end
  it 'should have a body' do
    page.find('body').should_not be_nil
    page.find('body').text.should_not == ''
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: This somehow sorted itself out. No idea how but, given you've supplied the only answer, and it seems plausible - I'm ticking this answer.